# Error solving differential equation

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

I am new to Mathematica, I am trying to solve a very basic differential equation and getting an error.
Can someone please assist as to why I am receiving a `NDSolve::dsvar` error?

```
m = 10000;
k = 10000;
w = 16.67*6.28;
F = 10;
S  = NDSolve[{m*x''[t] + c*x'[t] + k*x[t] == F*Sin[w*t]}, x''[0] == 0,
 x'[0] == 0, x[0] == 0, x, {t, 0, 20}]
```

Comment: What error did you receive?

Comment: You have `c` undefined and also 3 conditions for a 2nd order D.E

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 If `c` is defined elsewhere in the notebook, then `NDSolve[{m*x''[t] + c*x'[t] + k*x[t] == F*Sin[w*t], x''[0] == 0, 
  x'[0] == 0, x[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 20},  Method -> "EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"]` works even though over-specified because the constraints are consistent, and `NDSolve` isn't so picky with this method.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks for that. I did not know that `Method -> "EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"` would work even if overconstrained. I just pointed out that `c` is missing a definition from the block of code that I saw. Maybe it was a small mistake that would fix the issue.

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 Your comment is probably right, but not everyone posts complete code. Obviously, the OP is not using `"Residual"`, but I've always wondered why `NDSolve` complains about an extra condition if it's consistent. (E.g., why can't I ask for this solution, `NDSolve[{y'[x]^2 == 3 + y[x]^2, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == -2}, y, {x, 0, 1}]`, using any method?)

Comment: @MichaelE2 You mention a fair point to be honest. And I am playing a bit with `"Residual"` now. Seems like a very nice workaround for situations like the one you describe.

Answer (score 4):

You had few problems. No `c` defined. You had one extra initial conditions. (second order ode needs only 2 initial conditiosn). You did not put the initial conditions in the correct place.

Better to define `ic` on its own line and then use it later. This makes the code also easier to read.

Try this from clean kernel.

```
m=10000;
k=10000;
w=16.67*6.28;
F=10;
c=1;
ic={x'[0]==0,x[0]==0}
S=NDSolve[{m*x''[t]+c*x'[t]+k*x[t]==F*Sin[w*t],ic},x,{t,0,20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Btw, since Mathematica can solve this analytically, a better way is solve for the general form of the ode, then plugin specific values for the parameters in the generated generic solution.

This way you solve the ode only once and use the solution for different parameters.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
ic={x'[0]==0,x[0]==0}
sol=x[t]/.First@DSolve[{m*x''[t]+c*x'[t]+k*x[t]==F*Sin[w*t],ic},x[t],t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you can do

```
sol/.{m->10000,k->10000,w->Rationalize[16.67*6.28],F->10,c->1}
Plot[%,{t,0,10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]